# what does MD , LD etc stands for?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

In c++ compiling, there is MD, MT and LD. MT is obviously multi-thread, what about others?

Comment: "In c++ compiling, ..." should really read "In Micrsoft Visual C++,"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MD: use Multithread DLL Library

MT: use Multithread, statically-linked library

LD: Create a DLL

See [this MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3.aspx) for more info

Answer (score 1):

The command-line options for CL.EXE are all explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwkeyyhe%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). For your specific options:

- /MD Creates a multithreaded DLL using MSVCRT.lib.
- /MT Creates a multithreaded executable file using LIBCMT.lib.
- /LD Creates a dynamic-link library.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3(v=vs.80).aspx

Pretty complete and informative link regarding compilation flags.